# Throw exception on numeric overflow

Tags: java, java-8

Is it possible to throw some sort of runtime exception when integer overflow occurs rather then failing silently. For e.g.

```
int x = 100000000 * 1000000000;
```

print `1569325056` due to overflow and what I w'd like is to get some sort of runtime exception

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, Starting from Java-8 you can use the new [Exact](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact-int-int-) method, it will throw an exception(java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow) on overflow. E.g.

```
Math.multiplyExact(100000000, 1000000000);
```

Comment: @Trobbins Hope this time its fixed  :)

Comment: Why not check if the next value would cause overflow? `if (x > Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1) { throw new Exception("Overflow"); }`